# Ambiguity calculating size of structure

Tags: c

I am using code::blocks 12.11 (gcc) on a 32 bit OS. I have the following structure:

```
struct node 
{
int a;
float b;
char d;
struct node* c;
}
s1;
```

now individually,

```
sizeof(int);    sizeof(float);    sizeof(char);
```

gives output 4 4 1 bytes respectively.
so i calculate size of structure as 13 bytes.
But the following

```
sizeof(s1); or sizeof(struct node);
```

gives output 16bytes.

I am unable to figure out why this is so. Please help me out here.
Thanks.

Comment: The computer auto aligns memory to a certain bounds, so that an odd number of bytes will still occupy a certain range of memory that is "aligned."  For instance, I struct of 1 char, and int, and a char, will probably take 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The struct rounded to 32-bit (4-byte) chunks.  If you'd added 3 more chars, it would be the same size.